# Spring Boot cache request latency measurement

Tags: spring-boot, logging, redis

I am using Spring Boot 2 with Redis cache:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
```

Values are stored in Redis with `@Cacheable("key")` annotation.
I need to log request time during access to Redis. Is it possible?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @PSinha added an answer to this question. I did not find better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a final solution I decided to use `JProfiler` with method execution time monitoring:

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/main/methodCallRecording.html